# Overflow auto is not working

Tags: html, css

```css
.form select[multiple] {
    overflow: auto;
}
.form select[multiple] {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.form select[multiple] {
    border: 1px solid #a3a3a3;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    overflow-x:visible;
}
```

```html
<select id="specialitycenters" name="specialty-centers" size="7" multiple="true">
                   
                <option value="ARCH At Risk Children Center">ARCH At Risk Children Center</option><option value="ARMS Primary care services for HIV AIDS">ARMS Primary care services for HIV AIDS</option><option value="Adolescent - Young Adult Medicine">Adolescent - Young Adult Medicine</option><option value="After the Cancer Experience ACE   Late Effects Clinic   Long Term Followup">After the Cancer Experience ACE   Late Effects Clinic   Long Term Followup</option><option value="Allergy">Allergy</option><option value="Allergy and Immunology">Allergy and Immunology</option><option value="Analytical Imaging Modeling Center AIM">Analytical Imaging Modeling Center AIM</option><option value="Anesthesiology">Anesthesiology</option><option value="Asthma Management Program">Asthma Management Program</option><option value="Asthma Program">Asthma Program</option><option value="Audiology">Audiology</option><option value="Autism Developmental Disabilities">Autism Developmental Disabilities</option><option value="Autism Spectrum">Autism Spectrum</option><option value="Birth Anomalies FETAL">Birth Anomalies FETAL</option><option value="COACH Program">COACH Program</option><option value="Cancer and Blood Disorders">Cancer and Blood Disorders</option><option value="Cardiac Step down Unit">Cardiac Step down Unit</option><option value="Cardiology">Cardiology</option><option value="Cardiovascular ICU">Cardiovascular ICU</option><option value="Childrens Health Plan">Childrens Health Plan</option><option value="Childrens Medical Center Research Institute at UT Southwestern">Childrens Medical Center Research Institute at UT Southwestern</option><option value="Cleft Program">Cleft Program</option><option value="Clinical Nutrition">Clinical Nutrition</option><option value="Combined Allergy Sinus Clinic Cascade">Combined Allergy Sinus Clinic Cascade</option><option value="Complex Care Medical Services">Complex Care Medical Services</option><option value="Comprehensive  Stone Program">Comprehensive  Stone Program</option><option value="Comprehensive Care for Teenagers">Comprehensive Care for Teenagers</option><option value="Conditions - Treatments">Conditions - Treatments</option><option value="Conventional Orthodontics">Conventional Orthodontics</option><option value="Craniofacial Program">Craniofacial Program</option><option value="Critical Care PICU">Critical Care PICU</option><option value="Cystic Fibrosis Program">Cystic Fibrosis Program</option><option value="Demyelinating Disease Program">Demyelinating Disease Program</option><option value="Dentistry">Dentistry</option><option value="Dentistry -  Orthodontics">Dentistry -  Orthodontics</option><option value="Dentofacial Orthopaedics">Dentofacial Orthopaedics</option><option value="Dermatology">Dermatology</option><option value="Developmental Disabilities">Developmental Disabilities</option><option value="Diabetes">Diabetes</option><option value="Disease Management">Disease Management</option><option value="Disorders of Sexual Development">Disorders of Sexual Development</option><option value="Ear Nose and Throat ENT">Ear Nose and Throat ENT</option><option value="Eating Disorders">Eating Disorders</option><option value="Echocardiology">Echocardiology</option><option value="End Stage Kidney Renal Disease Program">End Stage Kidney Renal Disease Program</option><option value="Endocrinology">Endocrinology</option><option value="Epilepsy Center">Epilepsy Center</option><option value="Extracorporeal Membrane Oxygenation ECMO">Extracorporeal Membrane Oxygenation ECMO</option><option value="Facial Paralysis">Facial Paralysis</option><option value="Family Focused Center FFC for Deaf Hard of Hearing Children">Family Focused Center FFC for Deaf Hard of Hearing Children</option><option value="Female Genital Vaginal Reconstruction Program">Female Genital Vaginal Reconstruction Program</option><option value="Fetal Heart Program">Fetal Heart Program</option><option value="Fetal Neonatal">Fetal Neonatal</option><option value="Foster Care">Foster Care</option><option value="GENECIS">GENECIS</option><option value="Gastroenterology">Gastroenterology</option><option value="General Cardiology">General Cardiology</option><option value="General ENT">General ENT</option><option value="General Nephrology Program">General Nephrology Program</option><option value="General Neurology">General Neurology</option><option value="General Ophthalmology">General Ophthalmology</option><option value="Genetics">Genetics</option><option value="Growth Disorders">Growth Disorders</option><option value="Gynecology">Gynecology</option><option value="Hand Peripheral Nerve Surgery Clinic">Hand Peripheral Nerve Surgery Clinic</option><option value="Health and Wellness Alliance">Health and Wellness Alliance</option><option value="Healthy Eating">Healthy Eating</option><option value="Heart Center">Heart Center</option><option value="Hematology">Hematology</option><option value="Hepatology Liver">Hepatology Liver</option><option value="Hypertension Program">Hypertension Program</option><option value="Hypospadias, Male Genital Penal Reconstruction Program">Hypospadias, Male Genital Penal Reconstruction Program</option><option value="IBD Program">IBD Program</option><option value="Immunology">Immunology</option><option value="Infectious Diseases">Infectious Diseases</option><option value="Inpatient">Inpatient</option><option value="Intensive Outpatient">Intensive Outpatient</option><option value="International Adoption Medicine">International Adoption Medicine</option><option value="Intestinal Rehabilitation Program">Intestinal Rehabilitation Program</option><option value="Level IV NICU">Level IV NICU</option><option value="Liver Transplant">Liver Transplant</option><option value="Low Birth Weight">Low Birth Weight</option><option value="Low Birth Weight Clinic">Low Birth Weight Clinic</option><option value="Maternal Fetal Medicine">Maternal Fetal Medicine</option><option value="Medical Nutrition Therapy  MNT">Medical Nutrition Therapy  MNT</option><option value="Medical Psychiatric Co Morbidities">Medical Psychiatric Co Morbidities</option><option value="Minimally Invasive Robotic Surgery">Minimally Invasive Robotic Surgery</option><option value="Mood Disorders General Psychiatry">Mood Disorders General Psychiatry</option><option value="Motility Program">Motility Program</option><option value="Multidisciplinary Pediatric Aerodigestive Center -MPAC">Multidisciplinary Pediatric Aerodigestive Center -MPAC</option><option value="Neonatal Transport">Neonatal Transport</option><option value="Nephrology">Nephrology</option><option value="Neurodevelopmental Delay">Neurodevelopmental Delay</option><option value="Neurology">Neurology</option><option value="Neuromsucular Program">Neuromsucular Program</option><option value="Neurosurgery">Neurosurgery</option><option value="Nutrition Assessment Counseling">Nutrition Assessment Counseling</option><option value="Occupational Therapy">Occupational Therapy</option><option value="Oncology">Oncology</option><option value="Ophthalmology Eye">Ophthalmology Eye</option><option value="Orthodontics">Orthodontics</option><option value="Orthopedics">Orthopedics</option><option value="Otolaryngology">Otolaryngology</option><option value="Oupatient">Oupatient</option><option value="Pain Management">Pain Management</option><option value="Partial Hospitalization - Day Treatment">Partial Hospitalization - Day Treatment</option><option value="Pathology-Laboratory Medicine">Pathology-Laboratory Medicine</option><option value="Pediatric Gastroenterology Fellowship">Pediatric Gastroenterology Fellowship</option><option value="Physical Medicine - Rehabilitation">Physical Medicine - Rehabilitation</option><option value="Physical Therapy">Physical Therapy</option><option value="Physicians Quality Alliance">Physicians Quality Alliance</option><option value="Plastic - Craniofacial Surgery">Plastic - Craniofacial Surgery</option><option value="Prenatal Cardiac Consultation">Prenatal Cardiac Consultation</option><option value="Prenatal Care Program">Prenatal Care Program</option><option value="Program for Rare Genitourinary Birth Defects - Disorders">Program for Rare Genitourinary Birth Defects - Disorders</option><option value="Psychiatry - Psychology">Psychiatry - Psychology</option><option value="Psychiatry, Psychology - Neuropsychology Consultation Services">Psychiatry, Psychology - Neuropsychology Consultation Services</option><option value="Pulmonary Function Laboratory">Pulmonary Function Laboratory</option><option value="Pulmonology">Pulmonology</option><option value="REACH Clinic -Referral and Evaluation of At Risk Children">REACH Clinic -Referral and Evaluation of At Risk Children</option><option value="Radiology">Radiology</option><option value="Reconstructive Surgery">Reconstructive Surgery</option><option value="Respiratory Conditions">Respiratory Conditions</option><option value="Rheumatology">Rheumatology</option><option value="Skin Lesions">Skin Lesions</option><option value="Sleep">Sleep</option><option value="Sleep Evaluations">Sleep Evaluations</option><option value="Sleep Medicine">Sleep Medicine</option><option value="Sleep Studies Lab">Sleep Studies Lab</option><option value="Speech Language Pathology">Speech Language Pathology</option><option value="Spina Bifida - Neurogenic Bladder Program">Spina Bifida - Neurogenic Bladder Program</option><option value="Stem Cell Transplant">Stem Cell Transplant</option><option value="Strabismus">Strabismus</option><option value="Suicide Prevention And Resilience in Children -SPARC">Suicide Prevention And Resilience in Children -SPARC</option><option value="Surgery">Surgery</option><option value="Surgical Orthodontics">Surgical Orthodontics</option><option value="TelNICU">TelNICU</option><option value="The Caruth Center">The Caruth Center</option><option value="Therapeutic Endoscopy Program">Therapeutic Endoscopy Program</option><option value="Thyroid Center">Thyroid Center</option><option value="Tracheotomy Clinic">Tracheotomy Clinic</option><option value="Transition of Care">Transition of Care</option><option value="Transplant">Transplant</option><option value="Transport Services and Access Center">Transport Services and Access Center</option><option value="Trauma and Emergency Services">Trauma and Emergency Services</option><option value="Urology">Urology</option><option value="Vaccine Center">Vaccine Center</option><option value="Vascular">Vascular</option><option value="Vascular Anomalies">Vascular Anomalies</option><option value="Velopharyngeal Incompetence -VPI Clinic">Velopharyngeal Incompetence -VPI Clinic</option><option value="Voice - Flexible Endoscopic Evaluation of Swallowing -FEES">Voice - Flexible Endoscopic Evaluation of Swallowing -FEES</option><option value="Voice Disorders">Voice Disorders</option><option value="Voiding Dysfunction Program">Voiding Dysfunction Program</option><option value="Weight Management">Weight Management</option><option value="YMCA Program">YMCA Program</option><option value="ARCH At Risk Children Center">ARCH At Risk Children Center</option><option value="ARMS Primary care services for HIV AIDS">ARMS Primary care services for HIV AIDS</option><option value="Adolescent - Young Adult Medicine">Adolescent - Young Adult Medicine</option><option value="After the Cancer Experience ACE   Late Effects Clinic   Long Term Followup">After the Cancer Experience ACE   Late Effects Clinic   Long Term Followup</option><option value="Allergy">Allergy</option><option value="Allergy and Immunology">Allergy and Immunology</option><option value="Analytical Imaging Modeling Center AIM">Analytical Imaging Modeling Center AIM</option><option value="Anesthesiology">Anesthesiology</option><option value="Asthma Management Program">Asthma Management Program</option><option value="Asthma Program">Asthma Program</option><option value="Audiology">Audiology</option><option value="Autism Developmental Disabilities">Autism Developmental Disabilities</option><option value="Autism Spectrum">Autism Spectrum</option><option value="Birth Anomalies FETAL">Birth Anomalies FETAL</option><option value="COACH Program">COACH Program</option><option value="Cancer and Blood Disorders">Cancer and Blood Disorders</option><option value="Cardiac Step down Unit">Cardiac Step down Unit</option><option value="Cardiology">Cardiology</option><option value="Cardiovascular ICU">Cardiovascular ICU</option><option value="Childrens Health Plan">Childrens Health Plan</option><option value="Childrens Medical Center Research Institute at UT Southwestern">Childrens Medical Center Research Institute at UT Southwestern</option><option value="Cleft Program">Cleft Program</option><option value="Clinical Nutrition">Clinical Nutrition</option><option value="Combined Allergy Sinus Clinic Cascade">Combined Allergy Sinus Clinic Cascade</option><option value="Complex Care Medical Services">Complex Care Medical Services</option><option value="Comprehensive  Stone Program">Comprehensive  Stone Program</option><option value="Comprehensive Care for Teenagers">Comprehensive Care for Teenagers</option><option value="Conditions - Treatments">Conditions - Treatments</option><option value="Conventional Orthodontics">Conventional Orthodontics</option><option value="Craniofacial Program">Craniofacial Program</option><option value="Critical Care PICU">Critical Care PICU</option><option value="Cystic Fibrosis Program">Cystic Fibrosis Program</option><option value="Demyelinating Disease Program">Demyelinating Disease Program</option><option value="Dentistry">Dentistry</option><option value="Dentistry -  Orthodontics">Dentistry -  Orthodontics</option><option value="Dentofacial Orthopaedics">Dentofacial Orthopaedics</option><option value="Dermatology">Dermatology</option><option value="Developmental Disabilities">Developmental Disabilities</option><option value="Diabetes">Diabetes</option><option value="Disease Management">Disease Management</option><option value="Disorders of Sexual Development">Disorders of Sexual Development</option><option value="Ear Nose and Throat ENT">Ear Nose and Throat ENT</option><option value="Eating Disorders">Eating Disorders</option><option value="Echocardiology">Echocardiology</option><option value="End Stage Kidney Renal Disease Program">End Stage Kidney Renal Disease Program</option><option value="Endocrinology">Endocrinology</option><option value="Epilepsy Center">Epilepsy Center</option><option value="Extracorporeal Membrane Oxygenation ECMO">Extracorporeal Membrane Oxygenation ECMO</option><option value="Facial Paralysis">Facial Paralysis</option><option value="Family Focused Center FFC for Deaf Hard of Hearing Children">Family Focused Center FFC for Deaf Hard of Hearing Children</option><option value="Female Genital Vaginal Reconstruction Program">Female Genital Vaginal Reconstruction Program</option><option value="Fetal Heart Program">Fetal Heart Program</option><option value="Fetal Neonatal">Fetal Neonatal</option><option value="Foster Care">Foster Care</option><option value="GENECIS">GENECIS</option><option value="Gastroenterology">Gastroenterology</option><option value="General Cardiology">General Cardiology</option><option value="General ENT">General ENT</option><option value="General Nephrology Program">General Nephrology Program</option><option value="General Neurology">General Neurology</option><option value="General Ophthalmology">General Ophthalmology</option><option value="Genetics">Genetics</option><option value="Growth Disorders">Growth Disorders</option><option value="Gynecology">Gynecology</option><option value="Hand Peripheral Nerve Surgery Clinic">Hand Peripheral Nerve Surgery Clinic</option><option value="Health and Wellness Alliance">Health and Wellness Alliance</option><option value="Healthy Eating">Healthy Eating</option><option value="Heart Center">Heart Center</option><option value="Hematology">Hematology</option><option value="Hepatology Liver">Hepatology Liver</option><option value="Hypertension Program">Hypertension Program</option><option value="Hypospadias, Male Genital Penal Reconstruction Program">Hypospadias, Male Genital Penal Reconstruction Program</option><option value="IBD Program">IBD Program</option><option value="Immunology">Immunology</option><option value="Infectious Diseases">Infectious Diseases</option><option value="Inpatient">Inpatient</option><option value="Intensive Outpatient">Intensive Outpatient</option><option value="International Adoption Medicine">International Adoption Medicine</option><option value="Intestinal Rehabilitation Program">Intestinal Rehabilitation Program</option><option value="Level IV NICU">Level IV NICU</option><option value="Liver Transplant">Liver Transplant</option><option value="Low Birth Weight">Low Birth Weight</option><option value="Low Birth Weight Clinic">Low Birth Weight Clinic</option><option value="Maternal Fetal Medicine">Maternal Fetal Medicine</option><option value="Medical Nutrition Therapy  MNT">Medical Nutrition Therapy  MNT</option><option value="Medical Psychiatric Co Morbidities">Medical Psychiatric Co Morbidities</option><option value="Minimally Invasive Robotic Surgery">Minimally Invasive Robotic Surgery</option><option value="Mood Disorders General Psychiatry">Mood Disorders General Psychiatry</option><option value="Motility Program">Motility Program</option><option value="Multidisciplinary Pediatric Aerodigestive Center -MPAC">Multidisciplinary Pediatric Aerodigestive Center -MPAC</option><option value="Neonatal Transport">Neonatal Transport</option><option value="Nephrology">Nephrology</option><option value="Neurodevelopmental Delay">Neurodevelopmental Delay</option><option value="Neurology">Neurology</option><option value="Neuromsucular Program">Neuromsucular Program</option><option value="Neurosurgery">Neurosurgery</option><option value="Nutrition Assessment Counseling">Nutrition Assessment Counseling</option><option value="Occupational Therapy">Occupational Therapy</option><option value="Oncology">Oncology</option><option value="Ophthalmology Eye">Ophthalmology Eye</option><option value="Orthodontics">Orthodontics</option><option value="Orthopedics">Orthopedics</option><option value="Otolaryngology">Otolaryngology</option><option value="Oupatient">Oupatient</option><option value="Pain Management">Pain Management</option><option value="Partial Hospitalization - Day Treatment">Partial Hospitalization - Day Treatment</option><option value="Pathology-Laboratory Medicine">Pathology-Laboratory Medicine</option><option value="Pediatric Gastroenterology Fellowship">Pediatric Gastroenterology Fellowship</option><option value="Physical Medicine - Rehabilitation">Physical Medicine - Rehabilitation</option><option value="Physical Therapy">Physical Therapy</option><option value="Physicians Quality Alliance">Physicians Quality Alliance</option><option value="Plastic - Craniofacial Surgery">Plastic - Craniofacial Surgery</option><option value="Prenatal Cardiac Consultation">Prenatal Cardiac Consultation</option><option value="Prenatal Care Program">Prenatal Care Program</option><option value="Program for Rare Genitourinary Birth Defects - Disorders">Program for Rare Genitourinary Birth Defects - Disorders</option><option value="Psychiatry - Psychology">Psychiatry - Psychology</option><option value="Psychiatry, Psychology - Neuropsychology Consultation Services">Psychiatry, Psychology - Neuropsychology Consultation Services</option><option value="Pulmonary Function Laboratory">Pulmonary Function Laboratory</option><option value="Pulmonology">Pulmonology</option><option value="REACH Clinic -Referral and Evaluation of At Risk Children">REACH Clinic -Referral and Evaluation of At Risk Children</option><option value="Radiology">Radiology</option><option value="Reconstructive Surgery">Reconstructive Surgery</option><option value="Respiratory Conditions">Respiratory Conditions</option><option value="Rheumatology">Rheumatology</option><option value="Skin Lesions">Skin Lesions</option><option value="Sleep">Sleep</option><option value="Sleep Evaluations">Sleep Evaluations</option><option value="Sleep Medicine">Sleep Medicine</option><option value="Sleep Studies Lab">Sleep Studies Lab</option><option value="Speech Language Pathology">Speech Language Pathology</option><option value="Spina Bifida - Neurogenic Bladder Program">Spina Bifida - Neurogenic Bladder Program</option><option value="Stem Cell Transplant">Stem Cell Transplant</option><option value="Strabismus">Strabismus</option><option value="Suicide Prevention And Resilience in Children -SPARC">Suicide Prevention And Resilience in Children -SPARC</option><option value="Surgery">Surgery</option><option value="Surgical Orthodontics">Surgical Orthodontics</option><option value="TelNICU">TelNICU</option><option value="The Caruth Center">The Caruth Center</option><option value="Therapeutic Endoscopy Program">Therapeutic Endoscopy Program</option><option value="Thyroid Center">Thyroid Center</option><option value="Tracheotomy Clinic">Tracheotomy Clinic</option><option value="Transition of Care">Transition of Care</option><option value="Transplant">Transplant</option><option value="Transport Services and Access Center">Transport Services and Access Center</option><option value="Trauma and Emergency Services">Trauma and Emergency Services</option><option value="Urology">Urology</option><option value="Vaccine Center">Vaccine Center</option><option value="Vascular">Vascular</option><option value="Vascular Anomalies">Vascular Anomalies</option><option value="Velopharyngeal Incompetence -VPI Clinic">Velopharyngeal Incompetence -VPI Clinic</option><option value="Voice - Flexible Endoscopic Evaluation of Swallowing -FEES">Voice - Flexible Endoscopic Evaluation of Swallowing -FEES</option><option value="Voice Disorders">Voice Disorders</option><option value="Voiding Dysfunction Program">Voiding Dysfunction Program</option><option value="Weight Management">Weight Management</option><option value="YMCA Program">YMCA Program</option></select>
```

Here am using the multi select box, in this I need to have the scroll bar for horizontal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the width of the `select`. 
However, I don't know the cross-browser compatibility.

```css
.form select[multiple] {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #a3a3a3;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    overflow-x:visible;
}
```

```html
<form class="form"><select id="specialitycenters" name="specialty-centers" size="7" multiple="true">
                   
                <option value="ARCH At Risk Children Center">ARCH At Risk Children Center</option><option value="ARMS Primary care services for HIV AIDS">ARMS Primary care services for HIV AIDS</option><option value="Adolescent - Young Adult Medicine">Adolescent - Young Adult Medicine</option><option value="After the Cancer Experience ACE   Late Effects Clinic   Long Term Followup">After the Cancer Experience ACE   Late Effects Clinic   Long Term Followup</option><option value="Allergy">Allergy</option><option value="Allergy and Immunology">Allergy and Immunology</option><option value="Analytical Imaging Modeling Center AIM">Analytical Imaging Modeling Center AIM</option><option value="Anesthesiology">Anesthesiology</option><option value="Asthma Management Program">Asthma Management Program</option><option value="Asthma Program">Asthma Program</option><option value="Audiology">Audiology</option><option value="Autism Developmental Disabilities">Autism Developmental Disabilities</option><option value="Autism Spectrum">Autism Spectrum</option><option value="Birth Anomalies FETAL">Birth Anomalies FETAL</option><option value="COACH Program">COACH Program</option><option value="Cancer and Blood Disorders">Cancer and Blood Disorders</option><option value="Cardiac Step down Unit">Cardiac Step down Unit</option><option value="Cardiology">Cardiology</option><option value="Cardiovascular ICU">Cardiovascular ICU</option><option value="Childrens Health Plan">Childrens Health Plan</option><option value="Childrens Medical Center Research Institute at UT Southwestern">Childrens Medical Center Research Institute at UT Southwestern</option><option value="Cleft Program">Cleft Program</option><option value="Clinical Nutrition">Clinical Nutrition</option><option value="Combined Allergy Sinus Clinic Cascade">Combined Allergy Sinus Clinic Cascade</option><option value="Complex Care Medical Services">Complex Care Medical Services</option><option value="Comprehensive  Stone Program">Comprehensive  Stone Program</option><option value="Comprehensive Care for Teenagers">Comprehensive Care for Teenagers</option><option value="Conditions - Treatments">Conditions - Treatments</option><option value="Conventional Orthodontics">Conventional Orthodontics</option><option value="Craniofacial Program">Craniofacial Program</option><option value="Critical Care PICU">Critical Care PICU</option><option value="Cystic Fibrosis Program">Cystic Fibrosis Program</option><option value="Demyelinating Disease Program">Demyelinating Disease Program</option><option value="Dentistry">Dentistry</option><option value="Dentistry -  Orthodontics">Dentistry -  Orthodontics</option><option value="Dentofacial Orthopaedics">Dentofacial Orthopaedics</option><option value="Dermatology">Dermatology</option><option value="Developmental Disabilities">Developmental Disabilities</option><option value="Diabetes">Diabetes</option><option value="Disease Management">Disease Management</option><option value="Disorders of Sexual Development">Disorders of Sexual Development</option><option value="Ear Nose and Throat ENT">Ear Nose and Throat ENT</option><option value="Eating Disorders">Eating Disorders</option><option value="Echocardiology">Echocardiology</option><option value="End Stage Kidney Renal Disease Program">End Stage Kidney Renal Disease Program</option><option value="Endocrinology">Endocrinology</option><option value="Epilepsy Center">Epilepsy Center</option><option value="Extracorporeal Membrane Oxygenation ECMO">Extracorporeal Membrane Oxygenation ECMO</option><option value="Facial Paralysis">Facial Paralysis</option><option value="Family Focused Center FFC for Deaf Hard of Hearing Children">Family Focused Center FFC for Deaf Hard of Hearing Children</option><option value="Female Genital Vaginal Reconstruction Program">Female Genital Vaginal Reconstruction Program</option><option value="Fetal Heart Program">Fetal Heart Program</option><option value="Fetal Neonatal">Fetal Neonatal</option><option value="Foster Care">Foster Care</option><option value="GENECIS">GENECIS</option><option value="Gastroenterology">Gastroenterology</option><option value="General Cardiology">General Cardiology</option><option value="General ENT">General ENT</option><option value="General Nephrology Program">General Nephrology Program</option><option value="General Neurology">General Neurology</option><option value="General Ophthalmology">General Ophthalmology</option><option value="Genetics">Genetics</option><option value="Growth Disorders">Growth Disorders</option><option value="Gynecology">Gynecology</option><option value="Hand Peripheral Nerve Surgery Clinic">Hand Peripheral Nerve Surgery Clinic</option><option value="Health and Wellness Alliance">Health and Wellness Alliance</option><option value="Healthy Eating">Healthy Eating</option><option value="Heart Center">Heart Center</option><option value="Hematology">Hematology</option><option value="Hepatology Liver">Hepatology Liver</option><option value="Hypertension Program">Hypertension Program</option><option value="Hypospadias, Male Genital Penal Reconstruction Program">Hypospadias, Male Genital Penal Reconstruction Program</option><option value="IBD Program">IBD Program</option><option value="Immunology">Immunology</option><option value="Infectious Diseases">Infectious Diseases</option><option value="Inpatient">Inpatient</option><option value="Intensive Outpatient">Intensive Outpatient</option><option value="International Adoption Medicine">International Adoption Medicine</option><option value="Intestinal Rehabilitation Program">Intestinal Rehabilitation Program</option><option value="Level IV NICU">Level IV NICU</option><option value="Liver Transplant">Liver Transplant</option><option value="Low Birth Weight">Low Birth Weight</option><option value="Low Birth Weight Clinic">Low Birth Weight Clinic</option><option value="Maternal Fetal Medicine">Maternal Fetal Medicine</option><option value="Medical Nutrition Therapy  MNT">Medical Nutrition Therapy  MNT</option><option value="Medical Psychiatric Co Morbidities">Medical Psychiatric Co Morbidities</option><option value="Minimally Invasive Robotic Surgery">Minimally Invasive Robotic Surgery</option><option value="Mood Disorders General Psychiatry">Mood Disorders General Psychiatry</option><option value="Motility Program">Motility Program</option><option value="Multidisciplinary Pediatric Aerodigestive Center -MPAC">Multidisciplinary Pediatric Aerodigestive Center -MPAC</option><option value="Neonatal Transport">Neonatal Transport</option><option value="Nephrology">Nephrology</option><option value="Neurodevelopmental Delay">Neurodevelopmental Delay</option><option value="Neurology">Neurology</option><option value="Neuromsucular Program">Neuromsucular Program</option><option value="Neurosurgery">Neurosurgery</option><option value="Nutrition Assessment Counseling">Nutrition Assessment Counseling</option><option value="Occupational Therapy">Occupational Therapy</option><option value="Oncology">Oncology</option><option value="Ophthalmology Eye">Ophthalmology Eye</option><option value="Orthodontics">Orthodontics</option><option value="Orthopedics">Orthopedics</option><option value="Otolaryngology">Otolaryngology</option><option value="Oupatient">Oupatient</option><option value="Pain Management">Pain Management</option><option value="Partial Hospitalization - Day Treatment">Partial Hospitalization - Day Treatment</option><option value="Pathology-Laboratory Medicine">Pathology-Laboratory Medicine</option><option value="Pediatric Gastroenterology Fellowship">Pediatric Gastroenterology Fellowship</option><option value="Physical Medicine - Rehabilitation">Physical Medicine - Rehabilitation</option><option value="Physical Therapy">Physical Therapy</option><option value="Physicians Quality Alliance">Physicians Quality Alliance</option><option value="Plastic - Craniofacial Surgery">Plastic - Craniofacial Surgery</option><option value="Prenatal Cardiac Consultation">Prenatal Cardiac Consultation</option><option value="Prenatal Care Program">Prenatal Care Program</option><option value="Program for Rare Genitourinary Birth Defects - Disorders">Program for Rare Genitourinary Birth Defects - Disorders</option><option value="Psychiatry - Psychology">Psychiatry - Psychology</option><option value="Psychiatry, Psychology - Neuropsychology Consultation Services">Psychiatry, Psychology - Neuropsychology Consultation Services</option><option value="Pulmonary Function Laboratory">Pulmonary Function Laboratory</option><option value="Pulmonology">Pulmonology</option><option value="REACH Clinic -Referral and Evaluation of At Risk Children">REACH Clinic -Referral and Evaluation of At Risk Children</option><option value="Radiology">Radiology</option><option value="Reconstructive Surgery">Reconstructive Surgery</option><option value="Respiratory Conditions">Respiratory Conditions</option><option value="Rheumatology">Rheumatology</option><option value="Skin Lesions">Skin Lesions</option><option value="Sleep">Sleep</option><option value="Sleep Evaluations">Sleep Evaluations</option><option value="Sleep Medicine">Sleep Medicine</option><option value="Sleep Studies Lab">Sleep Studies Lab</option><option value="Speech Language Pathology">Speech Language Pathology</option><option value="Spina Bifida - Neurogenic Bladder Program">Spina Bifida - Neurogenic Bladder Program</option><option value="Stem Cell Transplant">Stem Cell Transplant</option><option value="Strabismus">Strabismus</option><option value="Suicide Prevention And Resilience in Children -SPARC">Suicide Prevention And Resilience in Children -SPARC</option><option value="Surgery">Surgery</option><option value="Surgical Orthodontics">Surgical Orthodontics</option><option value="TelNICU">TelNICU</option><option value="The Caruth Center">The Caruth Center</option><option value="Therapeutic Endoscopy Program">Therapeutic Endoscopy Program</option><option value="Thyroid Center">Thyroid Center</option><option value="Tracheotomy Clinic">Tracheotomy Clinic</option><option value="Transition of Care">Transition of Care</option><option value="Transplant">Transplant</option><option value="Transport Services and Access Center">Transport Services and Access Center</option><option value="Trauma and Emergency Services">Trauma and Emergency Services</option><option value="Urology">Urology</option><option value="Vaccine Center">Vaccine Center</option><option value="Vascular">Vascular</option><option value="Vascular Anomalies">Vascular Anomalies</option><option value="Velopharyngeal Incompetence -VPI Clinic">Velopharyngeal Incompetence -VPI Clinic</option><option value="Voice - Flexible Endoscopic Evaluation of Swallowing -FEES">Voice - Flexible Endoscopic Evaluation of Swallowing -FEES</option><option value="Voice Disorders">Voice Disorders</option><option value="Voiding Dysfunction Program">Voiding Dysfunction Program</option><option value="Weight Management">Weight Management</option><option value="YMCA Program">YMCA Program</option><option value="ARCH At Risk Children Center">ARCH At Risk Children Center</option><option value="ARMS Primary care services for HIV AIDS">ARMS Primary care services for HIV AIDS</option><option value="Adolescent - Young Adult Medicine">Adolescent - Young Adult Medicine</option><option value="After the Cancer Experience ACE   Late Effects Clinic   Long Term Followup">After the Cancer Experience ACE   Late Effects Clinic   Long Term Followup</option><option value="Allergy">Allergy</option><option value="Allergy and Immunology">Allergy and Immunology</option><option value="Analytical Imaging Modeling Center AIM">Analytical Imaging Modeling Center AIM</option><option value="Anesthesiology">Anesthesiology</option><option value="Asthma Management Program">Asthma Management Program</option><option value="Asthma Program">Asthma Program</option><option value="Audiology">Audiology</option><option value="Autism Developmental Disabilities">Autism Developmental Disabilities</option><option value="Autism Spectrum">Autism Spectrum</option><option value="Birth Anomalies FETAL">Birth Anomalies FETAL</option><option value="COACH Program">COACH Program</option><option value="Cancer and Blood Disorders">Cancer and Blood Disorders</option><option value="Cardiac Step down Unit">Cardiac Step down Unit</option><option value="Cardiology">Cardiology</option><option value="Cardiovascular ICU">Cardiovascular ICU</option><option value="Childrens Health Plan">Childrens Health Plan</option><option value="Childrens Medical Center Research Institute at UT Southwestern">Childrens Medical Center Research Institute at UT Southwestern</option><option value="Cleft Program">Cleft Program</option><option value="Clinical Nutrition">Clinical Nutrition</option><option value="Combined Allergy Sinus Clinic Cascade">Combined Allergy Sinus Clinic Cascade</option><option value="Complex Care Medical Services">Complex Care Medical Services</option><option value="Comprehensive  Stone Program">Comprehensive  Stone Program</option><option value="Comprehensive Care for Teenagers">Comprehensive Care for Teenagers</option><option value="Conditions - Treatments">Conditions - Treatments</option><option value="Conventional Orthodontics">Conventional Orthodontics</option><option value="Craniofacial Program">Craniofacial Program</option><option value="Critical Care PICU">Critical Care PICU</option><option value="Cystic Fibrosis Program">Cystic Fibrosis Program</option><option value="Demyelinating Disease Program">Demyelinating Disease Program</option><option value="Dentistry">Dentistry</option><option value="Dentistry -  Orthodontics">Dentistry -  Orthodontics</option><option value="Dentofacial Orthopaedics">Dentofacial Orthopaedics</option><option value="Dermatology">Dermatology</option><option value="Developmental Disabilities">Developmental Disabilities</option><option value="Diabetes">Diabetes</option><option value="Disease Management">Disease Management</option><option value="Disorders of Sexual Development">Disorders of Sexual Development</option><option value="Ear Nose and Throat ENT">Ear Nose and Throat ENT</option><option value="Eating Disorders">Eating Disorders</option><option value="Echocardiology">Echocardiology</option><option value="End Stage Kidney Renal Disease Program">End Stage Kidney Renal Disease Program</option><option value="Endocrinology">Endocrinology</option><option value="Epilepsy Center">Epilepsy Center</option><option value="Extracorporeal Membrane Oxygenation ECMO">Extracorporeal Membrane Oxygenation ECMO</option><option value="Facial Paralysis">Facial Paralysis</option><option value="Family Focused Center FFC for Deaf Hard of Hearing Children">Family Focused Center FFC for Deaf Hard of Hearing Children</option><option value="Female Genital Vaginal Reconstruction Program">Female Genital Vaginal Reconstruction Program</option><option value="Fetal Heart Program">Fetal Heart Program</option><option value="Fetal Neonatal">Fetal Neonatal</option><option value="Foster Care">Foster Care</option><option value="GENECIS">GENECIS</option><option value="Gastroenterology">Gastroenterology</option><option value="General Cardiology">General Cardiology</option><option value="General ENT">General ENT</option><option value="General Nephrology Program">General Nephrology Program</option><option value="General Neurology">General Neurology</option><option value="General Ophthalmology">General Ophthalmology</option><option value="Genetics">Genetics</option><option value="Growth Disorders">Growth Disorders</option><option value="Gynecology">Gynecology</option><option value="Hand Peripheral Nerve Surgery Clinic">Hand Peripheral Nerve Surgery Clinic</option><option value="Health and Wellness Alliance">Health and Wellness Alliance</option><option value="Healthy Eating">Healthy Eating</option><option value="Heart Center">Heart Center</option><option value="Hematology">Hematology</option><option value="Hepatology Liver">Hepatology Liver</option><option value="Hypertension Program">Hypertension Program</option><option value="Hypospadias, Male Genital Penal Reconstruction Program">Hypospadias, Male Genital Penal Reconstruction Program</option><option value="IBD Program">IBD Program</option><option value="Immunology">Immunology</option><option value="Infectious Diseases">Infectious Diseases</option><option value="Inpatient">Inpatient</option><option value="Intensive Outpatient">Intensive Outpatient</option><option value="International Adoption Medicine">International Adoption Medicine</option><option value="Intestinal Rehabilitation Program">Intestinal Rehabilitation Program</option><option value="Level IV NICU">Level IV NICU</option><option value="Liver Transplant">Liver Transplant</option><option value="Low Birth Weight">Low Birth Weight</option><option value="Low Birth Weight Clinic">Low Birth Weight Clinic</option><option value="Maternal Fetal Medicine">Maternal Fetal Medicine</option><option value="Medical Nutrition Therapy  MNT">Medical Nutrition Therapy  MNT</option><option value="Medical Psychiatric Co Morbidities">Medical Psychiatric Co Morbidities</option><option value="Minimally Invasive Robotic Surgery">Minimally Invasive Robotic Surgery</option><option value="Mood Disorders General Psychiatry">Mood Disorders General Psychiatry</option><option value="Motility Program">Motility Program</option><option value="Multidisciplinary Pediatric Aerodigestive Center -MPAC">Multidisciplinary Pediatric Aerodigestive Center -MPAC</option><option value="Neonatal Transport">Neonatal Transport</option><option value="Nephrology">Nephrology</option><option value="Neurodevelopmental Delay">Neurodevelopmental Delay</option><option value="Neurology">Neurology</option><option value="Neuromsucular Program">Neuromsucular Program</option><option value="Neurosurgery">Neurosurgery</option><option value="Nutrition Assessment Counseling">Nutrition Assessment Counseling</option><option value="Occupational Therapy">Occupational Therapy</option><option value="Oncology">Oncology</option><option value="Ophthalmology Eye">Ophthalmology Eye</option><option value="Orthodontics">Orthodontics</option><option value="Orthopedics">Orthopedics</option><option value="Otolaryngology">Otolaryngology</option><option value="Oupatient">Oupatient</option><option value="Pain Management">Pain Management</option><option value="Partial Hospitalization - Day Treatment">Partial Hospitalization - Day Treatment</option><option value="Pathology-Laboratory Medicine">Pathology-Laboratory Medicine</option><option value="Pediatric Gastroenterology Fellowship">Pediatric Gastroenterology Fellowship</option><option value="Physical Medicine - Rehabilitation">Physical Medicine - Rehabilitation</option><option value="Physical Therapy">Physical Therapy</option><option value="Physicians Quality Alliance">Physicians Quality Alliance</option><option value="Plastic - Craniofacial Surgery">Plastic - Craniofacial Surgery</option><option value="Prenatal Cardiac Consultation">Prenatal Cardiac Consultation</option><option value="Prenatal Care Program">Prenatal Care Program</option><option value="Program for Rare Genitourinary Birth Defects - Disorders">Program for Rare Genitourinary Birth Defects - Disorders</option><option value="Psychiatry - Psychology">Psychiatry - Psychology</option><option value="Psychiatry, Psychology - Neuropsychology Consultation Services">Psychiatry, Psychology - Neuropsychology Consultation Services</option><option value="Pulmonary Function Laboratory">Pulmonary Function Laboratory</option><option value="Pulmonology">Pulmonology</option><option value="REACH Clinic -Referral and Evaluation of At Risk Children">REACH Clinic -Referral and Evaluation of At Risk Children</option><option value="Radiology">Radiology</option><option value="Reconstructive Surgery">Reconstructive Surgery</option><option value="Respiratory Conditions">Respiratory Conditions</option><option value="Rheumatology">Rheumatology</option><option value="Skin Lesions">Skin Lesions</option><option value="Sleep">Sleep</option><option value="Sleep Evaluations">Sleep Evaluations</option><option value="Sleep Medicine">Sleep Medicine</option><option value="Sleep Studies Lab">Sleep Studies Lab</option><option value="Speech Language Pathology">Speech Language Pathology</option><option value="Spina Bifida - Neurogenic Bladder Program">Spina Bifida - Neurogenic Bladder Program</option><option value="Stem Cell Transplant">Stem Cell Transplant</option><option value="Strabismus">Strabismus</option><option value="Suicide Prevention And Resilience in Children -SPARC">Suicide Prevention And Resilience in Children -SPARC</option><option value="Surgery">Surgery</option><option value="Surgical Orthodontics">Surgical Orthodontics</option><option value="TelNICU">TelNICU</option><option value="The Caruth Center">The Caruth Center</option><option value="Therapeutic Endoscopy Program">Therapeutic Endoscopy Program</option><option value="Thyroid Center">Thyroid Center</option><option value="Tracheotomy Clinic">Tracheotomy Clinic</option><option value="Transition of Care">Transition of Care</option><option value="Transplant">Transplant</option><option value="Transport Services and Access Center">Transport Services and Access Center</option><option value="Trauma and Emergency Services">Trauma and Emergency Services</option><option value="Urology">Urology</option><option value="Vaccine Center">Vaccine Center</option><option value="Vascular">Vascular</option><option value="Vascular Anomalies">Vascular Anomalies</option><option value="Velopharyngeal Incompetence -VPI Clinic">Velopharyngeal Incompetence -VPI Clinic</option><option value="Voice - Flexible Endoscopic Evaluation of Swallowing -FEES">Voice - Flexible Endoscopic Evaluation of Swallowing -FEES</option><option value="Voice Disorders">Voice Disorders</option><option value="Voiding Dysfunction Program">Voiding Dysfunction Program</option><option value="Weight Management">Weight Management</option><option value="YMCA Program">YMCA Program</option></select></form>
```

Comment: it is working fine for chrome, can i have for firefox and IE

Comment: Really a nice solution! But as you pointed out cross-browser compatibility, you are right. I checked it in IE11 and horizontal scroll was gone.! May be later in future IE befriend developers.! ;)

Comment: @MedojuNarendar do you use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may try wrapping the `select` in a div and set the width for that.

Please Check the **[fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zge7eq59/)**

Comment: is it possible with out adding new div, i need to have for select box only

Comment: You may use JS, but that is not elegant just for scroll.

Comment: yes, in this code vertical scroll bar is showing up, but horizontal is not

Comment: Do you mean horizontal is showing up and vertical is not.? If so, well just set the height in same id #horizontal to get the vertical scroll-bar as well. example : #horizontal{width:300px;overflow-x:scroll;height:100px}. Here is updated fiddle having both scroll-bar : http://jsfiddle.net/zge7eq59/6/